# Cannot use the "include file" in JSP

Tags: jsp

I want to ask a question about the JSP page. I set the project in the following structure in order to manage the project efficiently. When I am in the list folder, main.jsp, I set the header as the following

```
<%@ include file="universe/header.jsp" %>
```

When I open the main.jsp, It shows the error

> cannot find the "jsp/list/universe/header.jsp"

the header.jsp and other classes cannot be read. Can anyone help me to solve the problem? thank you.

Class structure

```
webapp
|
|-- jsp
    |
    |-- list
    |   |
    |   |--main.jsp
    | 
    |-- universe
        |
        |-- header.jsp
        |-- footer.jsp
```

Comment: From your structure, it appears universe is under jsp/, not jsp/list/ as in the error message -- If I'm reading it correctly, then file="../universe/header.jsp" might work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a JSP include directive the path can be relative to the including page or absolute (then it has to start with a `/` and belongs to the webapplication root directory).

So in this case you have to set the path either to `../universe/header.jsp` or `/jsp/universe/header.jsp`.

Answer (score 0):

In JSP include directive, path can be relative.

You can use it this way

```
<%@ include file="/jsp/universe/header.jsp" %>
```

You can refer the directives on many sites. Best one is sun java website.

Or you can visit this page [Include Directive](http://apekshit.com/t/65/Include-Directive-in-JSP)

Answer (score -1):

It depends if your using the classpath to locate files. if your using classpath to locate your files then it should be inside your class folder

Comment: Sorry, but this is not true for JSP files in a web application. Here JSP files are not only simple resource files to locate. A web application in the JEE context has a defined structure. Look at http://www.jsptube.com/servlet-tutorials/web-application-directory-structure.html
Usually the /WEB-INF/classes and the JARs in /WEB-INF/lib are in the classpath and JSP files resides always outside of these folders.