# Jsp index exception when start tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, exception

I have a strange problem. Lets start with the error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [/index.jsp (line: 3, column: 1) File "/WEB-INF/jsp/includes.jsp" not found] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: 3, column: 1) File "/WEB-INF/jsp/includes.jsp" not found
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:322)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:467)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseFileDirectives(Parser.java:1779)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:135)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:119)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:193)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.__compile(Compiler.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet._serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is giving when I start tomcat (after the debug breaking in one class due a exception). I did try already to comment all code from all JSPs and checked if every file was on the deploy dir. Everything looks good and the strange thing is the application works fine. I cannot find the problem and I don't have any clue where I can start looking!

Someone can help me or already had a simmilar problem?

Thank you

Comment: What about `File "/WEB-INF/jsp/includes.jsp" not found`. Does this file exist in you project?

Comment: Yes there is a file includes in there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem of includes, an old webapp in the deploy directory that was giving that error. After removing that webapp that error went away, but the break of execution in the debug on tomcat startup still happens:

Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(boolean) line: not available [native method]

Answer (score 1):

If the file includes.jsp still exists in your project, try cleaning tomcat work directory. Than clean and rebuild your project and try again.

Comment: I did try to clean and no luck at all

Answer (score 0):

```
File "/WEB-INF/jsp/includes.jsp" not found] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: 3, column: 1)
```

If you are including this `includes.jsp` inside `index.jsp` then try it again after removing `/` from the beginning.

```
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jsp/includes.jsp" %>
```

---

Read more about Include directive [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110148/include-another-jsp-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404827/something-about-jsp-include-directive-and-jsp-include-tag/24405140#24405140)

Comment: right now I remove everything from all jsp files (jsut leave the string Hello world) to check if was something wrong with JSP includes or bad sintax and did not work... Same problem!!

Comment: If would be great if you can share both the jsp files location along with code.